# Laravel ffmpeg and laravel queue

Tags: laravel

Here' my situation I am using laravel ffmpeg and larvel queue to transcode videos. Everything seems to be working fine. The job processes great, but I am noticing that when its saves the video that was converted and compressed it saving it in the public app folder, but I wanted save the converted videos to my amazon s3 bucket.Can someone help with this

```
  //This is my controller

 public function store(StoreVideoRequest $request){

    $path=str_random(16). '.' . $request->video->getClientOriginalName();
   $request->video->move(public_path('app'), $path);


    $video=Video::create([
      'disk'=>'app',
       'original_name'=>$request->video->getClientOriginalName(),
       'path'=>$path,
       'title'=>$request->title,

    ]);

    ConvertVideoForStreaming::dispatch($video);

    return redirect('uploader')->with('message','Your video will be available shortly after we process it');
}


//This the job

 public function handle()
{
    // create a video format...
    $lowBitrateFormat = (new X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264'))->setKiloBitrate(500);

    $converted_name = $this->getCleanFileName($this->video->path);

    // open the uploaded video from the right disk...
    FFMpeg::fromDisk('local')
        ->open($this->video->path)

        // add the 'resize' filter...
        ->addFilter(function ($filters) {
            $filters->resize(new Dimension(320, 250));
        })

        // call the 'export' method...
        ->export()

        // tell the MediaExporter to which disk and in which format we want to export...
        ->toDisk('s3')
        ->inFormat($lowBitrateFormat)

        // call the 'save' method with a filename...
        ->save($converted_name);
            $imageName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($converted_name);
    // update the database so we know the convertion is done!
    $this->video->update([
        'converted_for_streaming_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'processed' => true,
        'stream_path' => $imageName
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows

```
FFMpeg::fromDisk('s3')
->open(filename.mp4)
->export()
->toDisk('s3')
->withVisibility('public')
->inFormat(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM())
->save('outputvideos.webm');
```